# Hiding and showing DOM elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I append the DOM elements dynamically, and when the data gets changed i use to hide and show lots of DOM elements. How do I improve my code?

```
str_user_details += '<tr ><td class="td_edu td_pad" colspan="2"><div class="div_edu"><span class="headings">Education </span> <span class="user_details_desc" id="alma_span'+key+'">'+alma_mater+'</span></div><div><span class="headings">Speciality </span> <span class="user_details_desc" id="speciality_span'+key+'">'+str_speciality+'</span></div>';         

$jq('.container').css('overflow-y','auto');
$jq('#create_account').css('display','none');
$jq('#wrong_user').css('display','none');               

if(details_length ==1) {
    $jq('.details_right_arrow').css('display','none');
} else {
    $jq('.details_right_arrow').css('display','block');
}
```

Its taking lots of 'if' and 'else' loops. how should i manage my code.

Comment: There's not enough info here to really answer the question.   A decently sized sample of the actual code would probably help.

Answer (score 2):

Well for one thing I know you can replace this...

```
$jq('#create_account').css('display','none');
$jq('#wrong_user').css('display','none');
```

With...

```
$jq('#create_account').hide();
$jq('#wrong_user').hide()
```

Same with...

```
if(details_length ==1) {
    $jq('.details_right_arrow').hide();
} else {
    $jq('.details_right_arrow').show()
}
```

As for the long str_user_details... there are _underscore templates you can use...

If you have more chains of if/else statements where you are doing similar operations maybe you can pull them out and have one method that applies to them all? I would need to see more to comment further.

Comment: The last one can probably be done with `$jq('.details_right_arrow').toggle(details_length != 1);`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will attach further code.
Also i'm loading a html page inside a div and animating that div, since the html page is heavy the animation looks choppy. Is there way to make it smoother ?